# How to display text for only a certain amount of time?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, delay, pong

I'm looking to display a message on the screen when a player wins, and get the text to display for 5 seconds, and then go back to the main menu start screen. Using the time.delay function however, my screen pauses and then displays the text in a flash, but then immediately goes to the startscreen. Is there a more efficient way of getting the text to be displayed for long enough to be read?

Below is the function I use to actually display the message:

```
def winnerPlayerOne():
    screen.fill(PINK)
    winnerP1Message = winnerFont.render("Congrats Player 1. You Win!", True, WHITE)
    screen.blit(winnerP1Message, ((400 - (winnerP1Message.get_width()/2)),(300 - (winnerP1Message.get_height()/2))))
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.delay(5000)

    startscreen()
```

And below this is how I call this function, within the main loop:

```
        if playeroneScore == 5:
            winnerPlayerOne()

        if playertwoScore == 5:
            winnerPlayerTwo()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you fix your indentation? Is `startscreen` in the function?

Comment: startscreen is called after all of the code above it, so that it goes to the startscreen after displaying the text.

Comment: Does that mean that it is part of the function?

Comment: Yes, it is part of the function.

Answer (score 2):

Benjamin's answer probably will work fine in your case. But if you want something that doesn't interfere with your game's visuals, I would consider setting a timer like so...

```
    WITHIN GAME LOOP:
        if gameWonScreen:
            screen.fill(PINK)
            winnerP1Message = winnerFont.render("Congrats Player 1. You Win!", True, WHITE)
            screen.blit(winnerP1Message, ((400 - (winnerP1Message.get_width()/2)),(300 - (winnerP1Message.get_height()/2))))
            timer = timer + elapsed/1000
            elapsed = fpsClock.tick(FPS)
            if timer > timeWinScreen:
                gameWonScreen = false
```

Initialize 'timeWinScreen' to the desired message duration at the start of the application and set 'timer' to '0' and gameWonScreen to 'true' when the player wins. Using elapsed = fpsClock.tick(FPS) will hold the time value since the last tick. You don't need to use it for this process (you could just use a fraction of your FPS) but using 'elapsed' is good practice because it helps with smoothing animations of certain objects.

Answer (score 1):

Try out `pygame.time.wait(5000)`. It should behave more in the way you are expecting. It does prevent any code running in the background as well, but that didn't seem like it would be an issue for your use case.

Comment: If I use time.wait, it doesn't even display the text, it just stops for 5 seconds, and then goes to the startscreen.

Comment: It looks like Owen Cummings has a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Remember that in the class below, time is not the way you measure time in pygame. It is  the number of loop happened in the main loop.

```
class disp_txt:

    def __init__(self,text,time,destination):
        self.text = text
        self.time = time
        self.destination = destination            
        self.shfnt = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsens",30,False)
        self.shtxt = self.shfnt.render(self.text,0,(255,0,0))
    def show(self,surface):
        if self.time>0:
            surface.blit(self.shtxt,self.destination)
        self.time -= 1
hint = disp_txt("text",100,(100,400)) #example
hint.show(screen)   #in the main loop or where you are drawing
```